# A null value becomes 0 in Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 drop-down lists with different names, and I'm trying to query in just one field.

I'm using a jQuery function wherein if `item 1` is selected, the drop-down list 1 will be displayed, and if the `item 2` is selected, the drop-down list 2 will be displayed.

This is how I populated my drop-down list from the mysql database and tables:

```
     <div id="minquep">
       <label>Branch</label>
          <SELECT name="user_min"> 
              <OPTION VALUE="0">Choose a branch
              <?=$minq_options?> 
          </SELECT> 
     </div>
    <div id="albury">
        <label>Branch</label>
          <SELECT name="user_branch"> 
              <OPTION VALUE="0">Choose a branch
              <?=$al_options?> 
          </SELECT>
```

And this is how I insert queries into mysql by filling out the form with drop-down lists in it:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(branch) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['user_branch'])).",".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['user_min']))."')";


if($_REQUEST['user_branch']= ""){

    ($_REQUEST['user_branch']) = NULL;
}


if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) { 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The user has been added successfully!\n");return true;</script>';
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=add_user.php\">";
}

else { 
echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); 
} 
}
```

The testing scenario is that, I choose the value under `<select name="user_min">`.
So I assume that sql will just bypass the result for `user_branch` because it is null. But it does prints **'0'** instead, after the insert query. For example, if the inserted `($_REQUEST['user_min'])` value is "Brisbane" and the ($_REQUEST['user_branch']) value is `null` (because I didn't selected any value under the `user_branch` drop-down list), the branch field should just become "Brisbane", knowing that `user_branch` is `NULL`. But it does print "BRISBANE" with **0**, like **0, Brisbane** in my mysql table.

How can I fix this?

I already tried putting an `if` condition, it did not work.

```
if($_REQUEST['user_branch']= ""){

        ($_REQUEST['user_branch']) = NULL;
    }
```

I've also tried changing the **user_min** into same name `user_branch`, but it does not get the selected value, instead of **Brisbane** it just prints *'0'*

Comment: You could avoid a lot of the `mysql_real_escape_string` ruckus by using PDO or `mysqli` with placeholders. The `mysql_query` method should not be used in new applications as it is inherently unsafe. Good to see proper escaping, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things -

1. you are setting user_branch = NULL after the $sql.
2. You are using quotes around value. It's fine non-Null values -you need to check if there is NULL value then don't use quotes in your $sql.
3. You are using single "=" in your IF statement. This is failing your If statement. Change it to `if($var == '')`

**Update**

Some suggestions based on your existing code - however there are other best practices to achieve what you are trying to achieve....

```
$user_branch =  $_REQUEST['user_branch'];
$user_min =  $_REQUEST['user_min']; 
//you should validate above values first 

if$user_branch == "" || $user_min == "") {
    $db_value = "NULL"; 
} else 
{
$db_value = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($user_branch.','.$user_min))."'";
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(branch) values (".$db_value.")";
```

Comment: Should i remove the .mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes and so on? & where should I put the NULL setting for user_branch? Before the $sql query?

Comment: @HappyApe you've still got an `'` inside the `values()` in the query (at the end), that'll throw an error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 0, then change:

```
<option value="0">Chose a Branch</option>
```

To:

```
<option value="">Chose a Branch</option>
```

Otherwise it will get passed through the form as `0`

Also, your PHP code won't work as you want it to:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) { 
  // do this before the query
  if($_REQUEST['user_branch']== ""){ // note the extra = in there, so you aren't assigning the variable, you are compairing
    $_REQUEST['user_branch'] = NULL; // no need for brackets round the variable
  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(branch) values (".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['user_branch'])).",".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['user_min'])).")"; // you had single quotes around everything inside the VALUES() function

  if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The user has been added successfully!\n");return true;</script>';
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=add_user.php\">";
  }
  else { 
    echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved half of my problem but the query just becomes **,Brisbane** with comma before the word Brisbane.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reg(Name ,Email) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['Name']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['Email']))."')";
```

This is my code. Here I found error of Undefined index.